# Need to rescue encrypted hard drive, Ubuntu is not booting

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery

I'm having trouble booting my Ubuntu 14.04. I have set a administrator password for BIOS which appears at startup. Once I enter that the system is supposed to go to the screen that shows the password prompt for my encrypted hard disk. Instead it is going into a screen that shows the output

```
[   0.048959] Ignoring BGRT: invalid status 0 (expected1)
[   1.065608] ACPI PCC probe failed.
BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands
(inittramfs)
```

If I boot through previous versions or recovery mode then I get the screen with this output:

```
Begin: Loading essential drivers...done.
Begin: Running/scripts/init-premount...done.
Begin: Mounting root file system...begin: running/scripts/local-top...
[ 3.915672] random: lvm urandom read with 75 bits of entropy available
reading all physical volumes. this may take a while...
No volume groups found
No volume groups found
Begin: Waiting for encrypted source device... ...
```

Then it goes into this screenshot:

[image]

The last line is:

```
(initramfs) [ 300...] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
```

I tried:

- Booting from live USB. GParted shows `/dev/sda3` as unknown filesystem
- Mounting using https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-encrypt-directories-and-partitions-with-ecryptfs-on-debian/
- Tried (failed): `cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sda3`

The hard drive contains very important information which cannot be lost at any cost. Please only suggest solutions if you are sure there is not a risk of data loss.

Comment: The line with `[Hardware Error]` sounds ***bad***, I don't know where the "Machine check events" are logged though, maybe in `/var/log`? And what was the output of `cryptsetup -v luksDump /dev/sda3`? Any results for `cryptsetup -v isLuks /dev/sda3`? Or maybe `lsblk` or `fdisk -l /dev/sda`? Does the live usb list any errors too?

Comment: Also, you may need to recover from your backups, any very important info should *always* have a backup copy, right?

Comment: Thanks to @cybea's link on MCE errors, they could be in /var/log/mcelog or found by running `/usr/sbin/mcelog > mcelog.out` (as root)

Answer (score 1):

*(Sorry everyone for not using comments - I still lack rep)*

Your "last line" [Sound like a hardware error](http://www.advancedclustering.com/act-kb/what-are-machine-check-exceptions-or-mce/)
try if your hard drive works in different computer

To me it seems like you should stick with `cryptsetup` because ecryptfs is normally used to decrypt home folders (at user login - not before system booted - and if you didn't do fancy stuff which you should remember)